# How to auto update the UI in SwiftUI when changes are made in realm database?

Tags: swiftui, realm

My realm **database structure** looks like this example:

```
class Person: Object, Identifiable {
   @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var name: String = "" 
   var dogs = RealmSwift.List<Dog>()
}

class Dog: Object, Identifiable {
   @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var name: String = "" 
   let human = RealmSwift.LinkingObjects<Person>(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
}
```

To simplify CRUD operations I have a **database manager**:

```
extension Realm {
public func safeWrite(_ block: (() throws -> Void)) throws {
    if isInWriteTransaction {
        try block()
    } else {
        try write(block)
    }
}
}

class DatabaseManager {

private let realm: Realm
public static let sharedInstance = DatabaseManager()

private init(){
    realm = try! Realm()
}

func save(_ obj: Object){
    do {
        try realm.safeWrite {
            realm.add(obj, update: .all)
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("error saving object: %@", [error])
    }
}

func save(_ obj: Object,_ block: () -> Void){
    do {
        try realm.safeWrite{
            realm.add(obj, update: .all)
            block()
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("error saving object: %@", [error])
    }
}


func save(_ objs: [Object]){
    do {
        try realm.safeWrite {
            realm.add(objs, update: .all)
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("error saving object: %@", [error])
    }
}

func fetchData<T: Object>(type: T.Type) -> Results<T>{
    let results: Results<T> = realm.objects(type)
    return results
}

func delete(_ obj: Object){
    do {
        try realm.safeWrite {
            realm.delete(obj)
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("error deleting object: %@", [error])
    }
}

func update(_ block: @escaping () -> Void){
    do {
        try realm.safeWrite{
            block()
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("error updating object: %@", [error])
    }
}
}
```

Now I have different views where I need to access my database and display some data. For this case I've created a **view model class**:

```
class PersonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let realm = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance
    @Published var persons: Results<Person> = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.fetchData(type: Person.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)

    public func fetch(){
        self.persons = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.fetchData(type: Person.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
    }

    public func addPerson(person: Person){
        realm.save(Person)
        self.fetch() // <---- necessary to update the UI: how to auto update?
    }
}
```

This view model class will be passed as an `@EnvironmentObject` to the views where I need the data. As you can see I need to fetch after each database operation all data again to have a "fresh updated" `Results<Person>`. I know that `Results<T>` are live, but it has no effect to the UI. Is there any way to auto updating all views when I do a change on the database without fetching all data manually again?

Comment: If your SwiftUI view has  `PersonViewModel` as `ObservedObject` then changes to `persons` will update view automatically.

Comment: As mentioned I pass the `PersonViewModel` as `EnvironmentObject`. Is this the reason that the UI won't be updated automatically? Since I need the data in many views, I think it's a little bit annoying to pass the `PersonViewModel` to all my views. Is there absolutely no way to solve this with `EnvironmentObject`?

Answer (score 0):

While Realm automatically updates collections as new data is deleted, added or changed, there needs to be a trigger that notifies your code of those changes.

That's a notification aka observer.

In this case there's an Results object `persons` populated with the fetchData function:

```
@Published var persons: Results<Person> = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.fetchData(type: Person.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
```

So when a person is deleted, added or changed the `persons` results object will be automatically updated. However to be notified of that, an observer needs to be added, and there are two components: a class level notification token and then a function to handle the event.

A notification token is defined like this (note a strong reference is needed to keep it alive)

```
var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil
```

and ensure it's deallocated when the view closes

```
deinit {
    self.notificationToken?.invalidate()
}
```

and then the code (in it's simplist form) that will execute when changes to people occurs

```
self.notificationToken = self.persons?.observe { changes in
    switch changes {
    case .initial:
        print("initial load")
        //the initial data is ready - reload tableviews/update ui etc

    case .update(_, _, _, _):
        print("update")
        //some change occurred, reload tableviews/update ui etc

    case .error(let error):
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Here's a link that covers this in depth [Collection Notifications](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/notifications#collection-notifications)